# Angular JS Problemsss

Tags: angularjs

I'm reading this book on angularJS and was trying the following example:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Listing 2-1</title>
    <script src="./js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function MyFirstCtrl($scope)
        {
            var employees=['Catherine Grant', 'Monica Grant', 'Christopher Grant', 'Jennifer Grant'];
            $scope.ourEmployees=employees;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyFirstCtrl">
    <h2>Number of Employees: {{ ourEmployees.length }}</h2>
</body>
                        </html>
```

But wen I run it, I get this:

Number of Employees: {{ ourEmployees.length }}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error in the console? Is it 1.3 version of angular? if so global controller declaration wont be picked up

Comment: 1.3.  how do I bring up the console in firefox?

Comment: You cannot use gloabally declared controller with 1.3. Check out linked answer. It should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks.  I found 1.2 so I can follow the book.